# MariaDB incorrect string value error with utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, utf8mb4

I changed database and table character set as `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8bm4_turkish_ci` on MariaDB for emoji support. While i can easily insert and select operations by connecting to the server through the terminal but i am getting "Incorrect String Value" error while i want to perform insert operation via Client (web application or MySQL workbench). Also, when i want to display the data with select, it is corrupt. In the meantime, i noticed another situation; even if the database and tables do not support utf8mb4 (i only used utf8 for testing), i can insert emoji through the terminal and even view it with select.

[image: Insert and Select operation through terminal]

[image: Insert and Select operation through MySQL Workbench]

The definitions on the my.cnf file are as follows;

```
[mysqld]
datadir        = /var/lib/mysql
socket         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user           = mysql
symbolic-links = 0
old_passwords  = 0

innodb_file_format        = Barracuda
default-storage-engine    = InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table     = 1
innodb_open_files         = 500
innodb_thread_concurrency = 24
lower_case_table_names    = 1
character-set-server      = utf8mb4
collation-server          = utf8mb4_turkish_ci
init-connect              = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci'

skip-character-set-client-handshake
innodb_large_prefix

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
skip-secure-auth
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Comment: i would be tempted to link [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279) as duplication.

Comment: seems that your PHPMyAdmin (or whatever you are using) doesn't set proper server connection names

Answer (score 2):

Also, the column in the table needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can check it.

Also, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` from the failing client; it may be wrong there.