# go-mysql-driver insert string into table gives error 1336 even using utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

Error message:

```
Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xA7test for column `mycolumn` at row 1
```

db connection code:

```golang
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb?charset=utf8mb4")
```

I tried running

```sql
SELECT
    `tables`.`TABLE_NAME`,
    `collations`.`character_set_name`
FROM
    `information_schema`.`TABLES` AS `tables`,
    `information_schema`.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS `collations`
WHERE
        `tables`.`table_schema` = DATABASE()
  AND `collations`.`collation_name` = `tables`.`table_collation`
;
```

and got this:

```
---------------------
| mytable | utf8mb4 |
---------------------
```

The string I'm trying to insert: `§test`

I looked at [MariaDB incorrect string value error with utf8mb4 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700901/mariadb-incorrect-string-value-error-with-utf8mb4-encoding) and other things, but everything I saw says to set collation to utf8mb4 and to set charset to utf8mb4 which I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value should be `\xC2\xA7test`. `\xA7` doesn't have a valid mapping in utf8(mb4).

```
select hex('§test')

C2A774657374
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eef9rsh5)